# Почему элемент на экране больше, чем указана ширина?

Tags: html, css, phonegap

Указал элементу ширину - 65%. Смотрю на экран - он явно больше 65%. Измеряю линейкой - предположение оправдалось, а именно 72.463... % оно занимало на экране. **WTF?, ну и как исправить?**

**UPDATE1** Если за 100% взять 125% экрана, то тот элемент как раз окажется 65%ным. Т.е. если экран был бы в 1.25 раз больше, то элемент был бы в самый раз

**UPDATE2** На компе всё нормально, проблема только на смарте

**UPDATE3** Ради теста поставил 100%. Элемент явно не влазит в рамки экрана

Comment: подробнее можно? какой элемент, где он лежит, что в нем лежит. 

> Измеряю линейкой - предположение оправдалось, а именно 72.463... %

представил дизайнера который мерит линейкой по монитору ширину, и потом высчитывает проценты )))

Comment: Обычный div, position:absolute. Ничего особенного. Разве что body у меня под position:fixed

Comment: >Измеряю линейкой

ваще агонь))) Все же программированием занимаетесь - нужно хоть немного высоких технологий...штангенциркуль хотя бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем поступил по народной мудрости - если оно увеличивается на 1.25, значит надо уменьшить на 1.25. **Итого:** width:52%

Answer (score 1):

`Padding`, `border` есть? Указанные проценты - это только `content-box` элемента.
Если да, то можно указать `box-sizing: border-box` и должно все встать на свои места (в ие7 не работает..

Comment: Нету ни бордеров, ни падингов, ничего. И причём тут ie? Я же метки поставил - mobile-web и phonegap. Phonegap это вообще webkit